# ASP.Net Core MVC Ajax json response

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a view where when the user selects 2 of the dropdown lists values, an AJAX method is kicked off to populate an additional dropdown list's values

The callback triggers, however I cannot work with the response.

I am probably doing more than one thing wrong, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I am very new to Asp.Net core mvc

My Controller code (simplified - parameters are being used and are working):

```
public IActionResult GetCodes(string location, string xType)
{
    return Json(new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "","" },
    { "Option1","120" },
    { "Option2","123" }
    });        
}
```

My jquery script on the view:

```
var ddl1val = $("#Location :selected").val().toLowerCase();
var ddl2val = $("#xType:selected").val().toLowerCase();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Ppl/GetCodes",          
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { location: ddl1val, xtype: ddl2val},
    success: function (data) {
        $("#ddlOptions").empty();

        var ops = '<option value=""></option>';

        alert(data); //returns [object Object]
        alert(data.Key); //returns undefined???

        //I need this to work
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            ops += '<option value="' + data[i].Key + '">' + data[i].Value + '</option>';
        $("#ddlOptions").html(ops);
    }
}
```

console.log(data) shows:

```
{"": "", Option1: "120", Option2: "123"}
```

I am not restricted to use JSON return, but it is lighter than xml, so I would prefer using it

Comment: _I cannot work with the response._ Please show us an example response

Comment: console.log(data) shows  {"": "", Option1: "120", Option2: "123"}

Comment: Please edit that into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialising a `Dictionary<>` to JSON will result in an object like this in your JS:

```
{
  "": "",
  "Option1": "120",
  "Option2": "123"
}
```

As such you should not use a `for` loop to enumerate it. As you're using jQuery you can use `$.map()` instead. Also note that you don't need to add the empty `option` as you include that in the response from the MVC endpoint. You also don't need to call `empty()` as you're overwriting the HTML of the `select` completely. Try this:

```js
var data = {
  "": "",
  "Option1": "120",
  "Option2": "123"
}

// inside the success callback:
var ops = $.map(data, function(v, k) {
  return '<option value="' + v + '">' + k + '</option>';
});
$("#ddlOptions").html(ops);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlOptions"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. I guess I need to learn how to use JSON properly